# Why does Windows 7 not provide Movie Maker?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-movie-maker

When I was using Windows XP SP 2, I was used to making movies using Movie Maker which was already provided.

Now, with Windows 7, why is there no Movie Maker included?

Comment: Hey man, did you solver your issue? Assign the answer to your question...

Comment: We aren't Microsoft. We can't say.

Answer (score 5):

Windows Movie Maker was discontinued due to the Windows **Live** Movie Maker, which belongs to the Windows Live Essencials, which is not embedded on Windows 7 by default(you must download and install it manually).

[Reference:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Movie_Maker)

> Development of Windows Movie Maker was abandoned after the release of
>   Windows Vista; its replacement, Windows Live Movie Maker, is included
>   with [Windows Live Essentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Essentials), a free download from Windows Live;
>   that does not have the same features as Windows Movie Maker. Windows
>   Movie Maker 2.6 for Vista is compatible with Windows 7 and recommended
>   by video editors, although Windows Movie Maker 2.6 is a stripped down
>   version and does not include video capture.
>
> [Windows Live Essentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Essentials) includes the following applications:
>
> - Windows Live Family Safety
> - Windows Live Mail
> - Windows Live Mesh
> - Windows Live Messenger
> - Windows Live Messenger Companion
> - Windows Live Movie Maker
> - Windows Live Photo Gallery
> - Windows Live Sign-in Assistant
> - Windows Live Writer
> - Bing Bar
> - Microsoft Outlook Hotmail Connector
> - Microsoft Silverlight
>
> Windows Live Essentials applications can be installed on Windows Vista
>   SP2, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 SP2 or Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: thanks,
but I try take the data from the program file Movie Maker 2 from Windows XP, and I copy it to Windows 7. after that i'm can use Movie Maker in Windows 7, but when i'm want to save the movie, that occurs the failed storage.. why??

Comment: @BrianTakan I would ask a separate question for that if you really have an actual problem.

Comment: @BrianTakan that could be possible due to not register the program in registry so you should install it not import from XP.

Comment: @slhck,
I will try the application you suggest, but previous I once try take data Movie Maker from the Windows XP 2  (program files), and it is true there is a problem when the movie storage.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 incorporates Windows Live Essentials products: `Windows Live Mail, Windows Live Photo Gallery and Windows Live Movie Maker`. You can download any of these [programs](http://download.live.com/?wa=wsignin1.0).

You can download and install older version of [Movie Maker](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34) which works great.

Comment: Downvoter can you please tell me the reason why you have downvoted?

Comment: Before you think it was me because I have another alike answer, it wasn't me...

Comment: @Diogo I know it wasn't you. But I still have question in mind why my answer downvoted while I listed the features and links correctly. Can you get that error in my answer? ;)

Comment: I'm having the same doubt as you :D

Comment: @avirk Link no more available.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't offer any version of movie maker for Windows 7 anymore, but it is available, links checked with virustotal. mentioned in this answer here-

https://web.archive.org/web/20220522155739/https://superuser.com/questions/1722106/how-can-i-install-windows-movie-maker-on-windows-7/