# how can I install windows movie maker on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-movie-maker

how can I install windows movie maker on windows 7?

I don't see an option for it

Comment: windows live essentials 2012 has it

Comment: Is it not installing with Windows Live Essentials?

Comment: it is installing with windows live essentials.. I haven't posted an answer yet though 'cos even though the file was only 100-150MB it was a slow download and I wanted to check it in virustotal after download. but the download was taking ages

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/movie-maker-download-is-not-available-on-windows-7-or-windows-8-1-24f28bff-84a1-0d75-5ddc-fd88fa3f3c90

Comment: @Moab  Just because microsoft doesn't offer it for download anymore doesn't mean it's no longer downloadable from anywhere and safely.. For a link to only mention that MS don't link to it anymore, and some FUD, is not that helpful.

Comment: @barlop I get you're writing this to add a canonical answer, but you've written such a low effort question that it is completely right that it will be closed. You failed to show your homework, demonstrate what you've tried, etc, all things this site requires of its questions. If you don't want this question closed and deleted, please improve it. The topic isn't bad, it's just this is a bad question in its current form.

Answer (score -2):

There are different versions of Movie Maker... 2.6,  6.1 and Windows Essentials 2012

This link has them

https://archive.org/details/WindowsMovieMaker_201711

Movie Maker 2.6.rar   4.70 MB  526d75f336abd8d821df33bc5afd3cb3c6faf7187096c127271e17ed7582101e
virustotal reports- "No security vendors and no sandboxes flagged this file as malicious"

Movie Maker 6.1.rar  19.35 MB
cc1ab60ae935cf2ba7c490f04dcc3aa9804096c09c39a21da972d006d558df19
virustotal reports- "No security vendors and no sandboxes flagged this file as malicious"

Windows Essentials 2012 16.4.3522.rar  130.08 MB
cf948227009d625d5dc6043b492b7a1d1c59c0e2e7221826d6cac3b67739f2c9
virustotal reports- "No security vendors and no sandboxes flagged this file as malicious"